# phpMyadmin allows to drop indexes for foreign key columns

Tags: indexing, phpmyadmin, mariadb, foreign-keys

Say I have these foreign keys defined in a MySQL table:

[image]

MySQL also auto-creates the required indexes for the foreign key columns:

[image]

Now if I try to drop the index for a foreign key column on this page, phpMyAdmin goes ahead and drops it. According to the query log, this is what happens:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = OFF
ALTER TABLE `bank_accounts` DROP INDEX `currency`
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON
```

The index is then gone from the table leaving the foreign key constraint in an inconsistent state. I have a couple questions regarding this:

- Is there any reason to have a foreign key constraint with no index on the column?
- Is there any way to disallow this behavior in phpMyAdmin?

Tested on phpMyAdmin v5.2.0.

**Update**: The issue seems to be related to MariaDB as it seems to allow removing indexes for foreign key columns with the checks disabled (tested on version 10.9). MySQL 8.0 doesn't allow that, apparently. It's still unclear why phpMyAdmin disables the foreign key checks before attempting to drop an index.

Comment: When I try to do this I get an error from the `ALTER TABLE` statement. It doesn't remove the index.

Comment: phpMyAdmin can't let you do something that MySQL prohibits.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see if the index was automatically recreated.

Comment: @Barmar, it is vaild to disable `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` for maintenance.  The question is why is PhpMyAdmin doing it on its own ?

Comment: Even when I disable foreign key checks, MySQL won't let me remove the index.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting. The queries in the OP were tested on MariaDB 10.9. I've just retested them from CLI in fresh docker containers for Mysql 8.0 and MariaDB 10.10 and can confirm that MySQL 8.0 disallows removing indexes for foreign key columns even with disabled foreign key checks, while MariaDB allows that. It's still unclear why phpMyAdmin disables the checks before attempting to drop an index.